# How to hide div's based on array or arraylist from servlet

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I have an arraylist coming from my admin.jsp with string false,false,true for ex

part of my user.jsp were i want to hide this div for ex based on first value of arraylist

```
<form action ="UserPredict" method = "post" >

    <div class="form-lables" style="display:none" >
        <h1><%out.print(admminresult.get(0));%>Vs <%out.print(admminresult.get(1));%> </h1>
        <label for="user_lic">Goals : </label><input id="user_lic" name="clm1g1" type="number" min="" max="10" step="1" value ="1"/>
        <label for="user_lic">Goals : </label><input id="user_lic" name="clm1g2" type="number" min="" max="10" step="1" value ="1"/>
    </div>
```

i think i may have to use javascript function but cant think of any idea, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can hide any element like this.

```
if ( <%out.print(admminresult.get(0)) == true ) {
var el = document.getElementById('yourDiv');
el.style.display = 'none';
//or show it again
el.style.display = 'block';
}
```

In jQuery, you can hide any element like this.

```
if ( <%out.print(admminresult.get(0)) == true ) {
 var el = $('#yourDiv');
 el.hide();

 //or show it again
 el.show();
}
```

Comment: if i want to use the javascript function i have to import my arraylist into javascript right ?

Comment: yeah i wasn't too sure on the jsp syntax you're using but yes, ideally. do you know how to go about doing that?

Comment: actually no i dont.